How to restrict Pydantic URL validation to specific hosts or websites
I'm currently working with Pydantic's URL type for URL validation in my Python project. However, it seems that Pydantic does not currently provide a built-in mechanism for this. So what is the best approach to restrict a URL to a specific list of hosts in Pydantic?
I have a pydantic model called Media which has an url attribute. I want the url to be restricted to certain websites or hosts."
from pydantic import BaseModel, AnyUrl

class Media(BaseModel):
    url: AnyUrl # the url host should only be from x.com or y.com


As you already mentioned there is no built-in support for doing so. Here an AfterValidator can do the job:
from typing import Annotated, TypeAlias

from pydantic import AfterValidator, AnyUrl, BaseModel

valid_hosts = {"www.google.com", "www.yahoo.com"}


def check_specific_hosts(url: AnyUrl) -> AnyUrl:
    if url.host in valid_hosts:
        return url
    raise ValueError("It's not in the list of accepted hosts")


AcceptedUrl: TypeAlias = Annotated[AnyUrl, AfterValidator(check_specific_hosts)]


class Media(BaseModel):
    url: AcceptedUrl


print(Media(url="http://www.google.com"))
try:
    print(Media(url="http://www.facebook.com"))
except ValueError as e:
    print(e)

output:
url=Url('http://www.google.com/')
1 validation error for Media
url
  Value error, It's not in the list of accepted hosts [type=value_error, input_value='http://www.facebook.com', input_type=str]
    For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.6/v/value_error


What you are seeking to do is some data validation. The way to do this is via a field validator or a model validator.
Have a look at:
https://docs.pydantic.dev/latest/concepts/validators/#before-after-wrap-and-plain-validators

Better repeat the essential parts or the linked content here. Show how this specific problem could be solved. Links can change or break, rendering your answer useless. You can [edit] and improve your answer.

Yes good point, I just though that it would be instructional for the OP to read some official documentation and read through the worked examples
